# How to check whether an object of an array equals an option value

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have the following select box on a form with an unknown number of options:

```
<select>
   <option value="v1">v1</option>
   <option value="v2">va2</option>
   <option value="v3">va3</option>
   <option value="v11">v11</option>
   <option value="v12">va12</option>
   <option value="v13">va13</option>
</select>​
```

I have the following array defined in javascript:

```
var checkValArray = ['v1', 'v2', 'v13'];
```

What I would like to do is go through every option of the select box and see whether an element of my array is equal to it.

What would be the best way to put this into practice?

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: My problem is the syntax of the for-loop. I do not know whether I can do sth. like jQuery.inArray(i,checkValArray) > -1

Comment: Why not? The only thing you need to do is to pass correct _value_, and not _index_, into `inArray`. BTW, this [doc page](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) has an example that you might find relevant to your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a very useful jQuery API method: [$.inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/). So it should be something like this:

```
var optionValue = $('select option:selected').val();
if ($.inArray(optionValue, checkValArray) !== -1) {
  // it's in
}
else {
  // it's not
}
```

For multiselects it may be used with something like...

```
$('select option:selected').each(function() {
   if ($.inArray(this.value, checkValArray) !== -1) { ... }
});
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you so much. I'll accept ir as answered asap.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('select option').each(function() {
  if ($.inArray($(this).val(),checkValArray)>-1) {
    // do something
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use $.inArray method to achieve this

```
var checkValArray = ['v1', 'v2', 'v13'];

var options = $('select option');

$.each(options , function(i){
    if($.inArray( $(this).val() , checkValArray) > -1){
       alert('Match Found');
    }
});
```

Check [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/wQbPP/)
​

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution without jQuery:

```
var selectitems = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
var items = selectitems.getElementsByTagName("option");
alert(items.length);
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
{
    alert(items[i].innerHTML);
}
```

​

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
var selectedArray = $("select#yourselectid").val();
var equal = $.extend($.extend([], checkValArray), selectedArray).length == checkValArray.length;
```